# How to recognise different symbols from their slope ? like (<,>,^) etc

Tags: image-processing, local-features, shape-analysis

i am trying to build a program in which user input a symbol with mouse and program recognise the symbol by saving mouse coordinates in array ,for this i have followed following steps:

1. Firstly check if line is straight or not by straight line equation.
2. I am able to recognise symbols like vertical,horizontal lines, forward and backward slash with the help of the slope of line.
3. but for >,<,^ i don't know what to do, for starters i have solved it like this, for example if < is to be recognised first symbol should be backward and second to be forward slash but this conflict with ^.

please let me know if there's another method for solving this problem.

Comment: If you have straight lines, even partial, I would suggest using the Hough transform. It converts lines to points, so you can look for maxima etc. to find if you have lines in a specific range of slopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way of doing it would be:

1. Extract [LBP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) feature vectors for the reference symbols are store it.
2. Now extract LBP feature vector of the test symbol.
3. Compare it with the list of available reference feature vectors and choose the one with minimum difference.

This method can also be extended to other symbols.

Comment: Why local binary patterns?

Comment: Because it's very easy to implement. This can be extended for other symbols that doesn't form straight lines also(Although it might need a classifier in larger set of symbols).

Comment: There might be other easy way too which I'm not aware of..